# IN expresson matching strings in JPQL

Tags: spring-data, jpql

Is there any way in `JPQL` to match query results with collection of strings passed in parameter using wildcards?

I am using `Spring Data queries` - for example I want to query table with values `("Johnson", "Smith", "Ford")` and get matches for collection `("%mi%", "%or")` which is `Smith` and `Ford` obviously.

`IN` expression won't work for a wildcard.

Is it possible to use nested selects or any other way to get the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a query with many `OR`s, like:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("%mi%", "%or");

String jpql = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE 1 = 1";
for (String name : names) {
    jpql += "OR e.name LIKE '" + name + "' ";
}
```

Only make sure to escape the names to prevent some SQL injection, since in this example you can't use `setParameter` from `Query`.